# AJAX post request not working, working fine with postman post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

Been trying to solve this issue for several days but to no avail. When I try to post to my rest I get my error message from error: function()

This is my ajax code that executes when I press the send button in my html site

```
var bord = {
           plasser: $plasser.val()
       };


 $.ajax({
      url: 'rest/bord',
      type: 'POST',
      data: bord,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(nyttBord){
          alert("sending successful");
          $bords.append("<li>id: "+ nyttBord.id +", plasser: "+ nyttBord.plasser + "</li>");
      },
      error: function(){
          alert("sending failed" + " plasser: " + bord.plasser);
      }
   });
```

My "BordResource" post method:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Bord addBord(Bord bord){
        return bordService.settInnBord(bord);
    }
```

I have tried sending post requests with postman with just the and it works just fine, so I'm kind of confused as to why this ajax function is getting an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your missing `contentType: "application/json",` and change `dataType: 'JSON',` into `dataType: 'json',`,
 so add it into your code like this

```
   type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(bord),
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: Ye didn't know that was a thing sorry, kind of new to this site